# Сортировка матрицы в заданной области

Tags: c++, матрицы

Как отсортировать числа в матрице по убыванию в заданной области без флага перестановки, используя функцию `swap`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я дошёл до этого момента (на картинке), но числа в строках должны идти в порядке убывания справа налево, а не наоборот, и я немного не понимаю как это реализовать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я тут вижу не сортировку, а забивание нулями остальной части матрицы...

Comment: Берете обычную сортировку по убыванию. В каждой строке передаете в неё итераторы (указатели) на начало и конец диапазона, который надо сортировать.